# Unable to scroll Collection view inside Table view cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have looked at the similar questions, and I still am not sure exactly what's going on. I feel like it might be something simple that is missing so I apologize in advance if so. My collection view inside table view cell is **not scrolling** and **not responding to didSelectItemAt** method. The project compiles correctly and looks exactly as needed for testing, but the horizontal scrolling and touches will not work. Another interesting note is that the table view responds to `didSelectRowAt` in the custom cell, but the collection view cells do not. Thank you in advance.

Per similar questions and answers, I have tried the following things:

- `cell.selectionStyle = .none` for the table cell that contains collection view
- `return nil` in the tableViews `willSelectRowAt` method for the cell with collection view

**PostViewController.swift**

```
class PostViewController: UIViewController {
        
    
    private let table: UITableView = {
        let table = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
        table.register(CustomTableCellTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CustomTableCellTableViewCell.id)
        table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableCell")
        return table
    }()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        self.view.addSubview(self.table)
        self.table.delegate = self
        self.table.dataSource = self
        
        
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.table.frame = self.view.bounds
    }
    

}


extension PostViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 170
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 2:
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomTableCellTableViewCell.id,
                                                           for: indexPath) as? CustomTableCellTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
            return cell
        default:
            
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCell", for: indexPath)
            return cell
        }
        
    
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    
    
}
```

** CustomTableCellTableViewCell.swift **

```
class CustomTableCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    
    static let id = "CustomTableCellTableViewCell"
    
    
    private let collection: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 128, height: 128)
        let collection = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collection.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell")
        collection.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        return collection
    }()
    
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        
        self.addSubview(self.collection)
        self.collection.delegate = self
        self.collection.dataSource = self
        
        
    }
    
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
    
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.collection.frame = self.bounds
    }
    

}


extension CustomTableCellTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        return cell
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Selected")
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subviews added to the UITableViewCell is behind contentView, which is blocking user input from reaching the **collection** view.

Collection view need to add in content view as -

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        contentView.addSubview(self.collection)
        self.collection.delegate = self
        self.collection.dataSource = self
        
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe I didn't see that.

Comment: Its okay. Happy developing.