# Unable to scroll Collection view inside Table view cell (created in Storyboard)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

There is a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69968965/unable-to-scroll-collection-view-inside-table-view-cell), but the solution doesn't solve anything for me, mainly because my embedded collection view is already inside the table view cell's content view (I created it in storyboard).

Is there some setting that I need to check to allow my collection view to scroll? It seems that the parent table view cell is eating up all gestures.

Comment: Please add code what have you done so far. So that we could help you out.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not much to show other than screenshooting a bunch of storyboard stuff. I literally just have a table view, and within the cell's content view, I have a collection view. Everything else is default storyboard values. If you try it I'm sure it won't work for you either. There has to be some way to enable this behavior, because it doesn't look like it's the default.

Answer (score 1):

TableViewController.swift

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.collectionView.dataSource = self
    cell.collectionView.delegate = self
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath)
    return cell
}

}
```

CustomTableViewCell.swift

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

You can find my demo project here
https://github.com/MattiaPell/CollectionView-inside-a-TableViewCell

Comment: Hmmmm...doesn't look like the collection view is scrollable

Comment: The code you posted does not show anything about making this scrollable or which properties should be set.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in my case it was simple as not having `User Interaction Enabled` check marked for my child collection view.